# Installing packages on the project level with Go

Tags: go

I started working with Go recently and I noticed that when I run `go get <some_url>` packages get installed in c://users/[user]/go/pkg. I was wondering is there a way to install packages inside of the project root, like I would do with `npm install` when working with node? Same behavior if I use `go mod init <my_proj>`. It appears that `go mod init <my_proj>` only installs my project inside c://users/[user]/go/pkg.

Thanks.

Comment: `go help mod vendor`. But just because this is good in npm doesn't mean it is the most sensible way to do it in Go too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you asking that because you want to vendor your dependencies. By default dependencies are stored in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` directory, but modules system also [supports vendoring](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Modules_and_vendoring). [Here is doc](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away) on how you can use it:

```
go mod vendor
```

will create vendor directory in project's root and store your dependencies there. Then, if you want to build/test/etc project using dependencies from vendor, you need to run `go build/test` with `-mod=vendor` flag(since go1.14 this flag is added automatically if there's vendor directory in your package).